# ValueError while trying to fit to a sklearn model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a linear regression model with just one predictor variable for a Retail Dataset. The predictor variable I'm trying to use is known as `Description`.

The Description column contains numerical values of the product category and the data type of the column, initially, was int64.

```
**InvoiceNo CustomerID StockCode Quantity   Description Country Year Month Day  dayofWeek HourofDay**
    4501    14730.0   3171        2            1324.0      35   2011    3   28      0        12
    2220    14442.0   1483        2             368.0       6   2011    1   27      3         9
    5736    15145.0   2498       12            2799.0      35   2011    4   26      1        16
    3347    12678.0   1809       12              48.0      13   2011    2   28      0        11
    14246   14179.0   1510        1             953.0      35   2011    10  18      1         1
```

When I tried to fit the model with just that, it worked perfectly.

```
X_train_1 = X_train['Description'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
X_train_1.columns = ['Description']
X_train_1.shape

mod = LinearRegression()
mod.fit(X_train_1, y_train)
```

However, when I changed the data type of the description variable from int64 to category, it is throwing me this error.

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-7243890f1de1> in <module>()
      4 
      5 mod = LinearRegression()
----> 6 mod.fit(X_train_1, y_train)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in take_nd(arr, indexer, axis, out, fill_value, allow_fill)
   1711         arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis, mask_info=mask_info
   1712     )
-> 1713     func(arr, indexer, out, fill_value)
   1714 
   1715     if flip_order:

pandas/_libs/algos_take_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.take_1d_int64_int64()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you change your datatype? Did you store it in the original dataframe? Looks like you have two duplicated rows in there

Comment: Try converting the descriptor to an ndarray, see https://github.com/pylablanche/gcForest/issues/12

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do by regressing with a categorical variable? The way you are running the code now.. the results will not make sense. You most likely need to encode them onehot

Comment: Can you show us the output of x_train_1.shape and y_train.shape. Thanks

Comment: @rftr Yes, I converted the parent dataframe's descriptor column to Categorical. And no, since I converted it directly, I don't have any duplicate columns.

Comment: @StupidWolf There are about 3800 levels in the description variable. Trying to convert all of them into binary variables and performing PCA was my first instinct. However, the number of rows is around 280000 and the no. of columns try out to be 3819 after converting them into dummy variables. Even Google Colab is not able to handle the pca. I even tried using sparse and minibatch pca, the colab notebook keeps crashing.

Comment: well.. then you cannot do linear regression on that... the levels are not ordered

Comment: @StupidWolf I know for a reason that the description column has all the information I need to make predictions. I've tried converting them into category dtype and that didn't yield any good results with a DTR. And the PCA route didn't work out. Do you have any suggestions as to how else I could approach this?

Comment: @Guillem `X_train_1.shape'  `(213585, 1)` `y_train.shape` `(213585, 1)`

Comment: you have a univariate response variable. And there's only 1 predictor, as far as I can tell. Whats stopping you from finding the mean for each category? Thats the result from linear regression anyway

Comment: @StupidWolf  That's a really good suggestion! It didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot! I'll try this.